# Get content of a text file over SFTP in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp

I have a problem with WinSCP module in PowerShell.
I use it this module for file transfer between two servers.
I have to check the content of a file on a remote server which contains the name of the files that I have to download.

In the WinSCP module there is no cmdlet like `Get-Content`.
Is there any way to achieve this without download the text file?

```
[System.Array]$remoteFiles = 
    Get-WinSCPChildItem -WinSCPSession $session -Path $remotePath -File:$true -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop |
            Where-Object {$_.Name -like $FileMask}

$remoteFiles | Get-Content
```

Comment: Since you apparently need the content anyway, why would you want to not download the file?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't want to change the folder structure. But this time it seems I have to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent of `Get-Content` in the WinSCP PowerShell module.

You have to download the file (to a temporary location) and read the downloaded file locally.

*Though note that, even if there was an equivalent of `Get-Content`, it would still "download" the file, although to a memory and not to local file.*